# Can anyone explain relation between <> and ⌊⌋ symbols (in probability theory?)?

Tags: notation

I see this:

$\left<nx\right> = nx - ⌊xn⌋$

in one of my exercise solutions for probability theory class. I found on wikipedia that <> means average and ⌊⌋ means greatest integer with the following examples:

$⌊4⌋ = 4, ⌊2.1⌋ = 2, ⌊2.9⌋ = 2, ⌊−2.6⌋ = −3$

Now I'm wondering why $⌊2.9⌋ = 2$ and $⌊−2.6⌋ = −3$.

I'm also wondering how the relationship $\left<nx\right> = nx - ⌊xn⌋$ is established.

Thanks!

Comment: $\langle \ast \rangle$ can mean a lot of different things, depending on the context.  It looks like it's being use here to denote the *fractional part* of a number.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part).

Answer (score 0):

Here $\left<x\right>$ is not average but fractional part and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ means the greatest integer $\le x$

Comment: You can also use: `\left< x\right>` to get $\left< x\right>$

Comment: For example, $\langle 17.6\rangle = 0.6$ and $\lfloor 17.6\rfloor = 17$.